# Populate a column with text (with no blank spaces) from another column based on an adjacent word in third column

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I want to **populate a column, with text (and No null/blank values)** from a column, based on an adjacent word found in third column. Please see the image below.

[image: Excel image]

I would like the **`Names`** in `Col A` having values :

- `Giants` to be placed under the Giant Column (Column D)
- `Bees` to be placed under the Bees Column (Column E) and so on.
- However `Names` values for Bees and Titanic should begin in the first available cell in their respective columns.

On a side note, The actual list has over 150 names and 9 different teams of uneven quantities.

So, any ideas how can I proceed with ?

Comment: You mean to say, Kyle & Sara in Giants (Column D), Jush & Jackie in Clo E and so ahead !!

Comment: Yes please, using a formula, so that I don't have to manually move them every time a new list is made. Thank you

Comment: Have you considered the use of pivot table?

Comment: @HomeFly, please check the Solution I've posted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In **D2** enter the array formula:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($A$1:$A$20,SMALL(IF($B$2:$B$20=D$1,ROW($B$2:$B$20)),ROW(1:1))),"")
```

and copy both across and downward:

[image]

Naturally replace the *20* with the real end-of-data.
**Array formulas** must be entered with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd> rather than just the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key.  If this is done correctly, the formula will appear with curly braces around it in the Formula Bar.

Comment: It works Amazingly, it is perfect, and thank you for the heads up about replacing the "20"! I am very appreciative of this assistance. This is my second year searching forums and youtube for this solution but I realize I didn't know what search words to use, it was very frustrating, so know that I am grateful. It works perfectly!!

Answer (score 1):

*I would like to suggest this Array Formula with different approach. Write the Formula in Cell D2 & fill to Right then Down.*

**N.B.** *Finish the Formula with Ctrl+Shift+Enter*.

```
{=IFERROR(INDEX($A$2:$A$13, MATCH(0, IF(D$1=$B$2:$B$13, COUNTIF(D$1:D1, $A$2:$A$13), ""), 0)),"")}
```

**Check the Screen Shot:**

[image]
**Note,** *This Formula will produce the same list, even if order of Names & Teams will change.*

Comment: This is amazing, thank you so much, I have been searching for two days straight, on forums and youtube trying to find this solution! It is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you again

Comment: @HomeFly, happy to help you,, if you feel you can accept this as Answer also. Keep Asking :-)

Comment: I tried to accept this one, with a tick, as well but I don't know how to do both. And the rules state not to post question or comments that aren't directly related to the topic nor thanks (which is really weird, as I am grateful for the help), but my thanks was the only way to let other viewers see that both methods worked for me. If you know how please instruct. thanks